# Why am I getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'removeStopWords' for my function?

Tags: python

I am trying to clean a twitter dataset and am not sure what this error means. I am calling my function `removeStopWords` into my main method however it does not seem to be accessing it correctly? Though I am not sure.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...main.py", line 193, in <module>
    obj = TwitterApplication(root)
  File "...\main.py", line 89, in __init__
    twitter = self.filterTweetList(df)
  File "...main.py", line 154, in filterTweetList
    return [[self.prepText(word) for word
  File "...main.py", line 154, in <listcomp>
    return [[self.prepText(word) for word
  File "...main.py", line 156, in <listcomp>
    if self.prepText(word) is not None]
  File "...src\main.py", line 140, in prepText
    return myWord.removeStopWords(
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'removeStopWords'
```

My code:

```
class MainApplication:

    def __init__(self, root):

        df = pd.read_csv("test_data.csv")

        if len(df) == 0:
            msg.showinfo('Empty file')
        else:
            twitter = self.filterTweetList(df)

        print(twitter[1]) # Print out first tweet that has been cleaned

    # Functions for data cleaning

    def removePunc(self, myWord):
        """Function to remove punctuation from string inputs"""
        if myWord is None:
            return myWord
        else:
            return re.sub('[.:;()/!&-*@$,?^\d+]', '', myWord)

    def removeAscii(self, myWord):
        """Function to remove ascii from string input"""
        if myWord is None:
            return myWord
        else:
            return str(re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', '', myWord.decode('utf-8').strip()))

    def lemmatize(self, myWord):
        wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
        """Function to lemmatize words"""
        if myWord is None:
            return myWord
        else:
            return str(wnl.lemmatize(myWord))

    def removeStopWords(self, myWord):
        """Function to remove stop words"""
        #newStopWords = ['amp', 'rt', 'https', 'http']
       # stopwords.append(newStopWords)
        if myWord is None:
            return myWord
        if myWord not in str(stopwords.words('english')):
            return myWord

    def removeLinkUser(self, myWord):
        """Function to remove web addresses and twitter handles"""
        if not myWord.startswith('@') and not myWord.startswith('http'):
            return myWord

    def prepText(self, myWord):
        """Final text pre-processing function"""
        return myWord.removeStopWords(
            myWord.lemmatize(
                myWord.removeAscii(
                    myWord.removePunc(
                        myWord.removeLinkUser(
                            myWord.lower()
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )

    def filterTweetList(self, tweetList):
        """Remove stop words, lemmatize, and clean all tweets"""
        return [[self.prepText(word) for word
                 in tweet.split()
                 if self.prepText(word) is not None]
                for tweet in tweetList]
```

Comment: Would you mind showing how are you calling the function in `main.py`? It seems you're passing a string in place of a tokenized array to the function.

Comment: Apparently, myWord is a string. However, you don't show us where it is initialized, so we can't say much more.

Comment: @YashvanderBamel I have updated the code. It now contains everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```py
def prepText(self, myWord):
        """Final text pre-processing function"""
        return myWord.removeStopWords(
            myWord.lemmatize(
                myWord.removeAscii(
                    myWord.removePunc(
                        myWord.removeLinkUser(
                            myWord.lower()
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
```

should likely be this

```py
def prepText(self, myWord):
        """Final text pre-processing function"""
        return self.removeStopWords(
            self.lemmatize(
                self.removeAscii(
                    self.removePunc(
                        self.removeLinkUser(
                            myWord.lower()
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
```

assuming that myWord is supposed to be a string. (as it was when the error was thrown) myWord would only have all of those functions if it where of Type TwitterApplication.

As mentioned in the comments on your question it would also be good to know from where the class and it's functions are being called.

Comment: That appears to have solved the issue however there is a new error: ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'```. I call the functions in the preptext function which is then called in the filtertweetlist function.

Comment: Why do you need to decode myWord? If it is of type 'str' as said in the error, you wouldn't need to do so. 
I found another stack overflow post that used the same regex as you did here to remove _non_ ascii chars. Is that what you are trying to do? If you really need utf-8 you should create a utf-8 encoded bytes object at the end using `bytes(myWord, 'utf-8)`